# Loading a dataset with 20000 attributes in Weka.

Tags: weka

I am referring a gene expression dataset from the UCI Machine Learning repository, to run some classifiers on it using Weka. (Link:- https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/gene+expression+cancer+RNA-Seq#). This database has 800 samples(rows), and each sample has 20531 attributes(columns). Thanks to a large number of columns, the entire dataset cannot be loaded in Weka. Is there any way to load the dataset in Weka successfully?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `the entire dataset cannot be loaded in Weka`? Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: Yes. File '~/data.csv' not recognised as a 'CSV data files' file. Reason: 3 Problem encountered on Line 2.